# What's the issue in getting the values from dynamically appended table row fields in post array after submitting the form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post, html-table

I've an HTML form. This form is containing HTML table. The actual HTML table is very large. For your reference I'm showing below the HTML code of a form with table containing only two rows:

```
<form action="rebates.php" role="form" method="post">
  <div style="margin-left: 12px" class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="company_name" class="col-lg-4">Manufacturer </label>
        <div class="col-lg-7">
          <select id="company_name" name="company_name" class="form-control">
            <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Manufacturer</option>
            <option value="33" >Eywa Solutions</option>
            <option value="37" >Amazon</option>
            <option value="40" >Test</option>
            <option value="42" >RK</option>
            <option value="46" >Santa Margherita</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: -61px" class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="product_id" class="col-lg-3">Product </label>
          <div class="col-lg-7">
            <select id="product_id" name="product_id" class="form-control">
              <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Product</option>
              <option value="5" >Chesse</option>
              <option value="8" >Laptop an</option>
              <option value="9" >Prosecco</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br/> 
    <div class="col-lg-2"></div>            
      <div class="col-md-8">   
        <div style="overflow:auto" class="well">      
          <button style="float:right; margin-bottom: 20px" class="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon-plus"></i> &nbsp;Add New Rebate</button>
          <br/>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table   id="blacklistgrid"  class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr  id="Row1">
                  <th style="vertical-align:middle" >Pack Of</th>
                  <th style="vertical-align:middle">Quantity</th>
                  <th style="vertical-align:middle">Volume</th>
                  <th style="vertical-align:middle">Unit</th>
                  <th style="vertical-align:middle">Rebate Amount</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr id="Row2">
                  <td><input type="text" name="pack[]" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="2" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="volume[]" value="750" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <select name="units[]" class="form-control">
                        <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Unit</option>
                        <option value="5" >Microsecond</option>
                        <option value="7" >oz</option>
                        <option value="9" >ml</option>
                        <option value="10" >L</option>
                        <option value="12" >gms</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="amount[]" value="3.00" class="form-control" size="9"/>
                  </td>
                </tr>            
                <tr>
                  <td><input type="text" name="pack[]" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="4" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="volume[]" value="750" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <select name="units[]" class="form-control">
                        <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Unit</option>
                        <option value="5" >Microsecond</option>
                        <option value="7" >oz</option>
                        <option value="9" >ml</option>
                        <option value="10" >L</option>
                        <option value="12" >gms</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="amount[]" value="7.00" class="form-control" size="9"/></td>
                </tr>                      
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <button style="float:right" class="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon-plus"></i> &nbsp;Add New Rebate</button>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- /span8 -->    
        <div class="row">
          <div  class="col-xs-5"></div>
          <div style="margin-left: -9px"  class="col-xs-5">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Preview</button>
          </div>                
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

I'm dynamically appending rows to the table by clicking on a button(the button is present in a  tag, you can see in above code). The various JQuery code snippets I tried for adding rows dynamically are as follows. All are working:

```
/*JQuery for appending rows at the end of table*/
<script language="javascript"> 
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.btnAdd').click(function () {
    var count = 1,
    first_row = $('#Row2');
    //while (count-- > 0) first_row.clone().appendTo('#blacklistgrid');
      while (count-- > 0) first_row.clone().removeAttr('id').appendTo('#blacklistgrid');
    //while (count-- > 0) $('#blacklistgrid > tbody:last').append(first_row.clone().removeAttr('id'));
    //while (count-- > 0) first_row.clone().appendTo('#blacklistgrid').attr('id','Row' + $('#blacklistgrid tr').length);
  });
});
</script>
```

From above code snippets you can suggest me the most optimum one. Now the issue I'm facing is if I append one or more rows at the end of table, fill data in the textfields of each appended row and submit the form by clicking on Submit button, in `$_POST` on rebates.php I'm not getting the data from appended rows. I'm getting the data only from the rows which are previously present when the page loads. So can anyone help me in getting the values from the dynamically appended rows also? Thanks for spending some of your valuable time in understanding my issue. Waiting for your precious replies. Still, if you need any further information regarding the question I can provide you the same.
I'm using following jQuery libraries:

```
    <script src="http://localhost/smart-rebate-web/web/js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/smart-rebate-web/web/js/libs/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/smart-rebate-web/web/js/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://localhost/smart-rebate-web/web/js/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>

    <script src="http://localhost/smart-rebate-web/web/js/Application.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/smart-rebate-web/web/js/demo/validation.js"></script>
```

Comment: What jQuery version are you using ? This should work perfectly fine, i just tested it. The problem you have is that when someone adds some data to the first row, you  copy that data out when you append it

Comment: @seblaze:I've updated my question. You can see the jQuery libraries I'm using at the bottom of question body.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i tested and works fine:

the .html file :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

  var first_row = $('#Row2').clone();
  $('.btnAdd').click(function () {
    var count = 1;

    first_row.clone().removeAttr('id').appendTo('#blacklistgrid');

  });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="formdata.php" role="form" method="post">
  <div style="margin-left: 12px" class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="company_name" class="col-lg-4">Manufacturer </label>
        <div class="col-lg-7">
          <select id="company_name" name="company_name" class="form-control">
            <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Manufacturer</option>
            <option value="33" >Eywa Solutions</option>
            <option value="37" >Amazon</option>
            <option value="40" >Test</option>
            <option value="42" >RK</option>
            <option value="46" >Santa Margherita</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: -61px" class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="product_id" class="col-lg-3">Product </label>
          <div class="col-lg-7">
            <select id="product_id" name="product_id" class="form-control">
              <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Product</option>
              <option value="5" >Chesse</option>
              <option value="8" >Laptop an</option>
              <option value="9" >Prosecco</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br/> 
    <div class="col-lg-2"></div>            
      <div class="col-md-8">   
        <div style="overflow:auto" class="well">      
          <button style="float:right; margin-bottom: 20px" class="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon-plus"></i> &nbsp;Add New Rebate</button>
          <br/>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table   id="blacklistgrid"  class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr  id="Row1">
                  <th style="vertical-align:middle" >Pack Of</th>
                  <th style="vertical-align:middle">Quantity</th>
                  <th style="vertical-align:middle">Volume</th>
                  <th style="vertical-align:middle">Unit</th>
                  <th style="vertical-align:middle">Rebate Amount</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr id="Row2">
                  <td><input type="text" name="pack[]" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="2" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="volume[]" value="750" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <select name="units[]" class="form-control">
                        <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Unit</option>
                        <option value="5" >Microsecond</option>
                        <option value="7" >oz</option>
                        <option value="9" >ml</option>
                        <option value="10" >L</option>
                        <option value="12" >gms</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="amount[]" value="3.00" class="form-control" size="9"/>
                  </td>
                </tr>            
                <tr>
                  <td><input type="text" name="pack[]" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="4" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="volume[]" value="750" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <select name="units[]" class="form-control">
                        <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Unit</option>
                        <option value="5" >Microsecond</option>
                        <option value="7" >oz</option>
                        <option value="9" >ml</option>
                        <option value="10" >L</option>
                        <option value="12" >gms</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="amount[]" value="7.00" class="form-control" size="9"/></td>
                </tr>                      
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <button style="float:right" class="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon-plus"></i> &nbsp;Add New Rebate</button>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- /span8 -->    
        <div class="row">
          <div  class="col-xs-5"></div>
          <div style="margin-left: -9px"  class="col-xs-5">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Preview</button>
          </div>                
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

formdata.php

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Sample data returned :

```
    Array
(
    [company_name] => 
    [product_id] => 5
    [pack] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
            [3] => d
        )

    [quantity] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
        )

    [volume] => Array
        (
            [0] => 750
            [1] => 750
            [2] => 750
            [3] => 750
        )

    [units] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 7
        )

    [amount] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3.00
            [1] => 7.00
            [2] => 3.00
            [3] => 3.00
        )

)
```

As you can see, it adds all the informations you are appending with jQuery

Comment: I tried your code, it worked perfect for me. I'm getting the values from appended table rows. Don't understanding why it's not happening in my case.